# clicking next page causes my page to slow down exponentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, pagespeed

this is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a website that displays images from the pixabay api. When i click the button, next, the next page of images is shown. The problem is that with each click, the page slows down at an exponential rate. I know this because i added a success console.log after every completion.

This is the image before:
[Image Link Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USWDG.jpg).

and after
[Image Link Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDl3Z.jpg)

I think the problem has something to do with the .getJSON call and the for loop inside that call, but I havn't been able to figure it out.

This is the Javascript and HTML

```js
/*
Pixabay api key:

*/
$(document).ready(function () {

    var searchValue = "rice"
    var defaultPage = 1;

    returnPhotos(searchValue, defaultPage);
    $("#searchForm").on("submit", function (event) {
        //obtain value from user input
        searchValue = $("#searchText").val();
        returnPhotos(searchValue, defaultPage);
        //stops form from submitting to a file
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});

/*
1. Return Photos from pixabey API
*/
function returnPhotos(searchValue, pageNum) {
    let key = "8712269-5b0ee0617ceeb0fd2f84487c3";
    let startURL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=" + key;
    let page = "&page=" + pageNum;
    let imagesPerPage = "&per_page=" + 22
    let addWH = "&min_width&min_height";
    let safeSearch = "&safesearch=true";
    let endingURL = "&q=" + searchValue + page + addWH + safeSearch + imagesPerPage;

    // activate api and get data
    $.getJSON(startURL + endingURL, function (data) {
        let image = data.hits;
        var imageLength = image.length;
        arrayLength = image.length;

        if (data) {
            let output = ""
            for (let x = 0; x < arrayLength; x++) {

                //imageObject contains information on each image passed through the array
                let imageObject = {
                    // id: image[x].id,
                    // pageURL: image[x].pageURL,
                    // tags: image[x].tags,
                    // previewURL: image[x].previewURL,
                    // previewWidth: image[x].previewWidth,
                    // previewHeight: image[x].previewHeight,
                    // webformatURL: image[x].webformatURL,
                    // webformatWidth: image[x].webformatWidth,
                    // webformatHeight: image[x].webformatHeight,
                    largeImageURL: image[x].largeImageURL,
                    // fullHDURL: image[x].fullHDURL,
                    // views: image[x].views,
                    // user_id: image[x].user_id,
                    // user: image[x].user,
                    // userImageURL: image[x].userImageURL
                }

                // output this template to the website
                output += `
                    <div class="brick">
                            <img src="${imageObject.largeImageURL}">
                    </div>
                `
            }

            $(".masonry").imagesLoaded(function () {
                localStorage.clear();
                $(".masonry").html(output);
            });
            console.log("success");
        } else {
            console.log("Didn't work");
        }

        getPage(searchValue, pageNum, arrayLength);
        // console.log(arrayLength);
    });
}




/*
2. INCREASE/Decrease PAGE
*/
function getPage(searchValue, defaultPage, max) {
    if (defaultPage <= max + 1) {
        $("#pagination2").click(function () {
            if (defaultPage <= max) {
                defaultPage++;
                returnPhotos(searchValue, defaultPage);
                console.log(1);
            }

            $(".pageNumber").html("Page " + defaultPage);
            console.log("This is the default page:", defaultPage);


        });

    }


    $("#pagination1").click(function () {
        if (defaultPage != 1) {
            defaultPage--;
            returnPhotos(searchValue, defaultPage);
            console.log(1);
        }
        $(".pageNumber").html("Page " + defaultPage);
        console.log("This is the default page:", defaultPage);
    });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">

    <link href="data:image/x-icon;base64,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"
        rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="nav">
            <h1>
                <a class="brand-logo" href="index.html">Photo Gallery</a>
            </h1>
        </nav>
        <!-- IMAGE search box-->
        <div class="header">
            <div>
                <h3 class="text-center">Search For Any Image</h3>
                <form id="searchForm" autocomplete="off">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchText" placeholder="Search Image Here">
                </form>
                <h4 class="from-pixabay">Images from Pixabay</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="paginations">
                <a href="#" id="pagination1">Previous</a>
                <p class="pageNumber">Page 1</p>
                <a href="#" id="pagination2">Next</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- IMAGES GO HERE -->
            <div class="masonry">

            </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Pre-footer -->
    <!--SECTION Contact-Footer -->
    <footer class="footer-section" id="contact">
        <div class="rows-container">
            <div class="footer-con">
                <div class="homepage-link">
                    <a href="http://rkdevelopment.org" target="_blank">
                        <h3>Rkdevelopment.org</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <ul class="social-list center">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://github.com/RexfordK" target="_blank">
                            <i class="ion-social-github"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/rexford-koduah" target="_blank">
                            <i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/rexfordk" target="_blank">
                            <i class="ion-fireball"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p>Copyright &copy; 2018 by Rexford Koduah. All rights reserved.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `getPage`, you are adding *another* `$("#pagination2").click` handler.  Which means the first time you click it, you do one ajax request.  The second time you do two, the third time you do three, etc.  You need to either only setup the click handler once, and make sure your logic reflects that, or clear the old one each time with `$("#pagination2").off('click').click(`

Comment: thank you for replaying, did you said I can clear the old one using:
$("#pagination2").off('click').click()?

I'm asking because I'm not sure really how to set up the click handler once, and at the same time, have the page reload the new images each time the button is clicked.

Comment: right, just add `.off('click')` right before the `.click`

Comment: IT WORKED! I used the $("#pagination2").off('click').click(function()) method and now I don't have the problem anymore!

Thank you so much dave! You are awesome!

Comment: awesome!  if it worked then you should accept the answer

Comment: I know I'm not the only one with this problem, hopefully this answer helps others with the same issue